# Change horizontal-scroll bar design without affecting vertical one

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to control the design of **horizontal** scrollbars of my site's content:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    background: #DDDDDD;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{
    background: #5D6C94;
}
```

But this also affects the browser's **vertical** scrollbar, making it almost unusable. Ideally, I would like to keep the vertical scrollbar, which usually appears on the right, untouched. How can I achieve that?

Note: I've managed to manipulate the vertical scrollbar's appearance by using the `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal` selector, but I would ideally like just the default design for that. I can't quite replicate how it looks in each browser.

Notice that I cannot control the class of these horizontal scrollbars since they are generated automatically.

Comment: You can give a unique class to your content and style the scrollbars only for that class — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/yv1jb3ke/  But they don't recommend to use this stuff at all — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME - I should have mentioned that I can't add classes to horizontal ones because they're dynamically generated.

Comment: it's 2022 now, and you still can't do it :/